# Creating two methods, returning boolean methods?

Tags: java

I was just wondering if I could have some help with my program, these require:

Now add two public methods to get and set the values of this new array: 
public void uncover(int thisCol, int thisRow)The uncovermethod changes the state of the specified square to false. Otherwise, if the input co-ordinates are outside the minefield or the square is already uncovered, it does nothing.

public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow)The isCoveredmethod returns true if the specified square is covered. Otherwise, if the input co-ordinates are outside the minefield or the square is not covered, it returns false.

I have attempted creating these methods below, but I don't think that they are correct, please can anyone take a look?

```
public void uncover(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
    if(thisCol <0 || thisRow < 0)
        return null;
    if(thisCol>=numCols || thisRow>=numRows)
        return null;
}

public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow){
    if(thisCol >0 || thisRow > 0)
        return true;
    if(thisCol>=numCols || thisRow>=numRows)
        return true;
    else;
        return null;
}
```

Comment: In your boolean you are not returning false. You are returning null.
A Boolean cannot be null.

Comment: You can't return something if you return type is void. You can only return.

Comment: cant void return null

Comment: You're not actually using this minefield array anywhere.

Comment: to CathalMF : a Boolean can be null, but a boolean cannot

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "[You can't return something if you return type is void. You can only return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364850/creating-two-methods-returning-boolean-methods/15364903#comment21709381_15364850)." What?

Comment: What he ment is that you can use return; like a break; inside a void method. Thats correct...

Comment: @LondonGraffs Hi, I noticed that you were having trouble writing good questions. I suggest you take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) - read it and try to ask a better-quality question next time :) As you've found, questions people view as bad will be quickly downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

first method:-

`public void uncover(int thisCol, int thisRow)`

This is a void method. that means you can't return any value`(null, true or false)`

Second method:-

`public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow)`

you can't return null because return type is boolean. so it should be `return false;`

above changes need to be corrected.after that you can try with your code.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding (in C#) is that "public void" indicates you are NOT returning anything to the caller. So in the "uncover" method, I would expect it to give you an error when trying to return Null.

Also, on the second one, I would expect to also see an error on the line "return null" since your return type is boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array is declared inside the class in a variabile:

```
private boolean thisArray[][];
```

Here is the correct `uncover` function:

```
public void uncover(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
    if(thisCol < 0 || thisRow < 0) return;
    if(thisCol >= numCols || thisRow >= numRows) return;
    thisArray[thisCol][thisRow] = true;
}
```

Corrections:

1. Return statement without values, because the function returns `void`
2. Assignemnt of array value in last row: `thisArray[thisCol][thisRow] = true`

Here is the correct `isCovered` function:

```
public boolean isCovered(int thisCol, int thisRow){
    if(thisCol < 0) return false;
    if(thisRow < 0) return false;
    if(thisCol >= numCols) return false;
    if(thisRow >= numRows) return false;
    return thisArray[thisCol][thisRow];
}
```

Corrections:

1. If coordinates are outside squares it must return `false`, you was returning `true`;
2. You was missing to check the effective value of the array, that I added in the last row: `return thisArray[thisCol][thisRow];`